# Stop an Android screen recording in an automated script

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb, appium

I'm building automated test scenarios in Appium (for an Android app), and am trying to figure out a way to start recording the screen during a specific moment, running some actions and then stopping the recording.

I could not find any screen record solution implemented in Appium, but found a neat adb shell command, `screenrecord`, that does exactly what it states. Now my problem is that the only obvious ways to stop the recording are to either set the exact time limit I need in the arguments, or to press Ctrl-C in the interactive shell:

```
2|shell@mako:/ $ screenrecord --help
Usage: screenrecord [options] <filename>

Android screenrecord v1.2.  Records the device's display to a .mp4 file.

Options:
--size WIDTHxHEIGHT
    Set the video size, e.g. "1280x720".  Default is the device's main
    display resolution (if supported), 1280x720 if not.  For best results,
    use a size supported by the AVC encoder.
--bit-rate RATE
    Set the video bit rate, in bits per second.  Value may be specified as
    bits or megabits, e.g. '4000000' is equivalent to '4M'.  Default 4Mbps.
--bugreport
    Add additional information, such as a timestamp overlay, that is helpful
    in videos captured to illustrate bugs.
--time-limit TIME
    Set the maximum recording time, in seconds.  Default / maximum is 180.
--verbose
    Display interesting information on stdout.
--help
    Show this message.

Recording continues until Ctrl-C is hit or the time limit is reached.
```

I could use `--time-limit`, but then I need to estimate how long any given recording should take within the tests, the memory usage will be far from optimal, etc.

Using Ctrl-C offers its own limitations, as it requires an interactive shell session, and my automations should include only simple shell commands:

```
adb -s DEVICE_UDID shell screenrecord /sdcard/Recordings/video.mp4
```

Does anyone know of a way to actively stop a recording?

Alternatively, does anyone know of how to record the screen using Appium?

Comment: very good question.. According to my knowledge  Appium does not support screen record. And there is no way you can stop adb screen record except timeout parameter & CTRL-C key event

Comment: `Ctrl-C` is nothing but `SIGINT`. Just send it to the `screenrecord` process - no "interactive shell session" required

Comment: Thanks, did not think of that. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you save the process whichever you ran the screenrecord, you can do kill with signal SIGINT that will work as you want.

For example:

```
process = adb shell
process.stdin = screenrecord test.mp4 &
```

and then when you want to kill it

```
process.stdin = pkill -2 screenrecord
```

Should work, give it a try

Comment: I believe that should be `pkill -l 2 screenrecord`?

Answer (score -1):

Once you start screenrecording, it starts adb process. So if you can kill started adb process then also screenrecording stops. For that you can first store all adb process before starting screen recording and then after screen recording whatever adb process is started, just kill the same. I implemented screen recording in below class. Code is self explanatory. please check. you can also check - http://easytestautomation.blogspot.in/2016/06/easy-to-record-screen-in-appium-for.html

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ScreenRecorder {


 private static List<String> ADBProcessIDsBeforeScreenRecording = null;
 private static List<String> ADBProcessIDsAfterScreenRecording = null;


 public static void StartScreenRecording(String CurrentTestMethodName)
   throws IOException {


  // Storing all ADB process ids before starting Screen Recording.
  ADBProcessIDsBeforeScreenRecording = getProcessIDs("adb.exe");


  // "Starting Screen Recording for Current TestMethod.
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd /c adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 1000000 //sdcard//"
      + CurrentTestMethodName + ".mp4");


 }


 public static void StopScreenRecording(String CurrentTestMethodName,
   String DirectoryToSaveRecordedScreen,
   boolean RemoveRecordedScreenFromDevice) throws IOException,
   InterruptedException {


  // Storing all ADB process ids after Screen Recording.
  ADBProcessIDsAfterScreenRecording = getProcessIDs("adb.exe");


  // killing ADB task using process id.
  // First we are trying to get ADB process id that is started due to ADB
  // screenrecord then killing the same.
  for (String id : ADBProcessIDsAfterScreenRecording) {
   boolean found = false;
   for (String tgtid : ADBProcessIDsBeforeScreenRecording) {
    if (tgtid.equals(id)) {
     found = true;
     break;
    }
   }
   if (!found) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /PID " + id);
    break;
   }
  }


  // Sleep time to save the recorded video in Device properly
  Thread.sleep(2000);


  // Pulling Screen Recording to PC/Machine
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
    "cmd /c adb pull //sdcard//" + CurrentTestMethodName + ".mp4 "
      + DirectoryToSaveRecordedScreen);
  // Sleep time to pull video from device to destination directory
  Thread.sleep(5000);


  if (RemoveRecordedScreenFromDevice) {
   // Deleting ScreenRecord from Device
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
     "cmd /c adb shell rm //sdcard//" + CurrentTestMethodName
       + ".mp4");
  }


 }


 //Method to get List of Process Ids using Process Name
 static List<String> getProcessIDs(String processName) {
  List<String> processIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
  try {
   String line;
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist /v /fo csv");
   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     p.getInputStream()));
   while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
     // Pid is after the 1st ", thus it's argument 3 after
     // splitting
     String currentProcessName = line.split("\"")[1];
     // Pid is after the 3rd ", thus it's argument 3 after
     // splitting
     String currentPID = line.split("\"")[3];
     if (currentProcessName.equalsIgnoreCase(processName)) {
      processIDs.add(currentPID);
     }
    }
   }
   input.close();
  } catch (Exception err) {
   err.printStackTrace();
  }
  return processIDs;
 }


}
```

Comment: This answer makes too many assumptions in the system and can cause too many unwanted artifacts. 
What if I want to run parallel tests? What if some other program uses adb at the same time? etc.